# Simplifying a trignometric function whose input is a trignometric function?

Tags: trigonometry

I have come across several problems in which at some point I get a trignometric function whose input is a tricnometric function, for instance:

tan (cos x) or sin (sec y).

If x (or y) is an unknown can this be simplified and how?

You can assume that the answer to the problem is the simplified equation and you are not expected to actually find x (or y). For instance I came across this problem while simplifing a equation for non-definite integration.

Comment: What sort of problem leads to that kind of expression?

Comment: I am doing integration with direct substitution.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Question: Find the integral of sec^4 x tan x. Working: if u=sec x then x=cos u an du/dx = -sin u. Then _S_ sec^4 x tan x dx= _S_ u^4 * tan (cos u) * -sin u du.

Comment: (I used _S_ to stand for the integral.)

Comment: In fact $\displaystyle \frac{d \sec(x)}{dx}=\sec(x)\tan(x)$ so you have $\displaystyle\int \sec^4(x) \tan(x) \, dx = \tfrac14 \sec^4(x) +C$

Comment: Thank you, but this was only one example, so if you have an answer to my origional question I would still appreciate it. I want to be able to answer the questions without having prior knowledge.

Comment: My guess is that if you find your answer to standard integrations is something like $\tan (\cos x)$ or $\sin (\sec y)$ then you may have already made a mistake.  The input to these trigonometric functions is an angle and the output is a ratio of lengths, usually unsuitable as the input to another trigonometric function.